# Replacing inline styles into generic classes

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I have a problem where there are lots of in-line styling in place with `padding-left :some_Value and margin-left: some value`.

```
<div class="row" style="padding-left: 40px">
</div>
```

How do we handle such things in generic and best manner. The problem is neither of these properties have `consistent and unique value`. Can we create some sort of function or mixin to handle this?.

Comment: I'm not understanding how you think Sass is going to help solve this problem.  Sass can only ever compile to CSS, and only the CSS is presented to the user.

Comment: @cimmanon: How do u remove these type of inline terms.

Comment: The same way you would with vanilla CSS?

Comment: A bit more info could be useful here. There's www.cssout.com but that just adds some nasty id's to the elements, which is not that useful imo. There's Nathan Smith's quick script that you can run just to strip the tags, but I'm not certain if it will help you achieve what you want. https://gist.github.com/nathansmith/262366

Answer (score 0):

The best practice - tedious as it is - would be to clean up the HTML: remove the inline styling (`style="padding-left: 40px"`) from it.  Intermingling styling and content in this manner is pretty much a worst practice.

You can use `!important` in your stylesheets to override the inline styles coming from the HTML. Example:

```
p {
  margin: 1rem;
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: #DDD !important;
}

<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.</p>
<p style="background-color: #99F">Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante.</p>
<p>Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
```

Note that !important is kind of a code smell - it's a bit hacky becuase you're already dealing with the sub-optimal inline styles from HTML. You can mix this with whatever Sass you've got going in your system.